Angular + ApexChart labels are not updated on .updateSeries() method call
I'm using apexChart + angular and want to update data(series) in chart dynamically using updateSeries() method. Data is being updated correctly, but X and Y labels are not. Here you can find the code snippet:
<div
  <apx-chart #chart
             [dataLabels]="chartOptions.dataLabels"
             [series]="chartOptions.series"
             [chart]="chartOptions.chart"
             [xaxis]="chartOptions.xaxis"
             [yaxis]="chartOptions.yaxis"
             [title]="chartOptions.title"
             [plotOptions]="chartOptions.plotOptions"
             [legend]="chartOptions.legend"
             [tooltip]="chartOptions.tooltip"
             [autoUpdateSeries]="chartOptions.autoUpdateSeries"
  ></apx-chart>
</div>

@ViewChild('chart') chart: ChartComponent;
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.chartOptions = {
      dataLabels: {enabled: false},
      autoUpdateSeries: true,
      tooltip: {
        x: {
          format: 'dd MMM, yyyy HH:mm'
        }
      },
      series: [],
      chart: {
        type: 'bar',
        height: 500,
        width: 1500,
        stacked: true,
        toolbar: {
          show: false,
        },
      },
      title: {
        text: 'Title',
        align: 'center',
      },
      xaxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
      },
      yaxis: {
        title: {
          text: 'Traffic (Mbps)',
        },
        labels: {
          formatter: (value) => `${value} (M) `,
        },
      },
      plotOptions: {
        bar: {
          horizontal: false,
          barHeight: '85%',
          columnWidth: '100%',
          borderRadius: 5,
          borderRadiusWhenStacked: 'all',
          distributed: false,
        },
      },
      legend: {
        show: true, // Show or hide the legend
        position: 'bottom', // Position: 'top', 'right', 'bottom', 'left'
        horizontalAlign: 'left', // Alignment: 'start', 'center', 'end'
        floating: false, // If true, the legend floats over the chart
        fontSize: '14px', // Font size
        fontWeight: 400, // Font weight
        labels: {
          colors: '#333', // Color of the labels
          useSeriesColors: false, // Use series colors for legend labels
        },
        itemMargin: {
          horizontal: 10, // Space between legend items
          vertical: 5,
        },
        
      },
    };
  }

public onEvent(event: any) {
    this.service.getData(event).subscribe(data => {
      this.chart.updateOptions({
      series: [
      {name: data.meta.legend.at(0), data: data.txBytes},
      {name: data.meta.legend.at(1), data: data.rxBytes},
    ]});
    });
  }

My wild guess is that I'm creating empty series and trying to update it afterwards. I've tried updateOptions() instead of updateSeries() as well, but without any luck. Any help would be highly appreciated!

The updateSeries method seems to update properly when I try it.
Another method you can use is directly setting the series property of chartOptions to a new array.
If these two do not work, try cdr.detectChanges() which might update the chart.
  constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  public onEvent(event: any) {
    of({
      txBytes: [15],
      rxBytes: [12],
      meta: {
        legend: ['asdf', 'qwer'],
      },
    }).subscribe((data) => {
      this.chart.updateSeries([
        { name: data.meta.legend[0], data: data.txBytes },
        { name: data.meta.legend[1], data: data.rxBytes },
      ]);
      // this.chartOptions.series = [
      //   { name: data.meta.legend[0], data: data.txBytes },
      //   { name: data.meta.legend[1], data: data.rxBytes },
      // ];
      this.cdr.detectChanges();
    });
  }

Full Code:
import { ChangeDetectorRef, Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { ChartComponent } from 'ng-apexcharts';
import { of } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  standalone: false,
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('chart') chart: ChartComponent;
  chartOptions: any;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.chartOptions = {
      dataLabels: { enabled: false },
      autoUpdateSeries: true,
      tooltip: {
        x: {
          format: 'dd MMM, yyyy HH:mm',
        },
      },
      series: [],
      chart: {
        type: 'bar',
        height: 500,
        width: 1500,
        stacked: true,
        toolbar: {
          show: false,
        },
      },
      title: {
        text: 'Title',
        align: 'center',
      },
      xaxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
      },
      yaxis: {
        title: {
          text: 'Traffic (Mbps)',
        },
        labels: {
          formatter: (value) => `${value} (M) `,
        },
      },
      plotOptions: {
        bar: {
          horizontal: false,
          barHeight: '85%',
          columnWidth: '100%',
          borderRadius: 5,
          borderRadiusWhenStacked: 'all',
          distributed: false,
        },
      },
      legend: {
        show: true, // Show or hide the legend
        position: 'bottom', // Position: 'top', 'right', 'bottom', 'left'
        horizontalAlign: 'left', // Alignment: 'start', 'center', 'end'
        floating: false, // If true, the legend floats over the chart
        fontSize: '14px', // Font size
        fontWeight: 400, // Font weight
        labels: {
          colors: '#333', // Color of the labels
          useSeriesColors: false, // Use series colors for legend labels
        },
        itemMargin: {
          horizontal: 10, // Space between legend items
          vertical: 5,
        },
      },
    };
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.onEvent({});
    }, 3000);
  }

  constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  public onEvent(event: any) {
    of({
      txBytes: [15],
      rxBytes: [12],
      meta: {
        legend: ['asdf', 'qwer'],
      },
    }).subscribe((data) => {
      this.chart.updateSeries([
        { name: data.meta.legend[0], data: data.txBytes },
        { name: data.meta.legend[1], data: data.rxBytes },
      ]);
      // this.chartOptions.series = [
      //   { name: data.meta.legend[0], data: data.txBytes },
      //   { name: data.meta.legend[1], data: data.rxBytes },
      // ];
      this.cdr.detectChanges();
    });
  }
}

Stackblitz Demo
